# Probability of forming a triangle within certain parameters

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

Stuck at problem 7.19, from "Understanding Probability by Henk Tijms". The problem statement is :

> You choose a number $v$ at random from (0, 1) and next, a number $w$ at random from (0, $1 − v$). What is the probability that a triangle can be formed with the side lengths $v$, $w$ and $1 − v − w$? Hint: represent $w$ as $y(1 − v)$,
> where $y$ is a random number from (0, 1).

I approached the problem by first, arriving at the conditions to form a triangle which are :

$$
v < \frac{1}{2}$$
$$w < \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{2} < v + w < 1
$$

Next, I drew an unit square and according to the above conditions, found an area where these conditions were favourable to form a triangle, which itself is a triangle, having the points (0,1/2), (1/2,1/2) & (1/2,0). Since this is exactly a half of the quarter square, I figured the probability is 1/8. But the actual answer is $\ln(2) - 0.5$. So, the real shape must have some curves which means that the probability calculation involves calculus but I can't figure out how. And also cannot understand how and why the hint might be helpful.

**Edited for clarity**: I don't understand why a) my solution is wrong, or b) is my approach wrong and c) how is that hint supposed to help me because I do not understand how to incorporate it.

Comment: Draw a square with the axes representing your two variables.  Then color regions in the square according to whether a triangle is formed or not.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The pdf for $w$ is $\frac 1{1-v}$ - integrating this w.r.t $v$ is what will give you the $\ln(2)$

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what went wrong, but a basic issue is that $W=Y(1-V)$ isn't independent from $V$. But the variables $Y$ and $V$ are, so try writing the constraints using $y$ rather than $w$.

Comment: "So, the real shape must have" Until this point, I think you were correct, your triangle is correct. But all points in this square don't have same probability to occur. All values $v$ have same probability, but it is not the case for $w$.  Maybe use the hint ; consider $y$, where $w=y(1-v)$ ; $y$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I did that. The result is [this](https://ibb.co/4MLpmTm).

Comment: @WW1 I haven't yet reached the part about distribution or density functions yet :(

Comment: The hint is urging you to get rid of $w=y(1-v)$ in favor of $y$, on the grounds that $v,y$ are then independent and uniformally distributed. This changes the expressions of your constraints, e.g., $w>1/2$ becomes $y>\frac12 (1-y)^{-1}$. Write the others and determine the allowed region.

Comment: @Jay.  If your square graph figure is correct, then you have your answer:  the ratio of green to red area.

Answer (score 1):

Given $v$, the density of $w$ is Uniform$[0,1-v]$, i.e.
$$
f_W(w)=\begin{cases}
\frac1{1-v}, & w\in [0,1-v]\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Hence the joint density of $V,W$ is
$$
f_{V,W}(v,w)=\begin{cases}
\frac1{1-v}, & w\in [0,1-v], \ v\in [0,1];\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Now you only need to compute
$$
I:=\iint_A f_{V,W} (v,w) dv dw=\iint_B \frac1{1-v} dv dw
$$
where $A=\{(v,w)\in \mathbb{R}^2: 0<v<1/2, 0<w<1/2,v+w>1/2\}$ and
$B=\{(v,w)\in \mathbb{R}^2: 0<v<1/2, \max(0,1/2-v)<w<\min(1/2,1-v)\}=\left\{(v,w)\in \mathbb{R}^2: 0<v<\frac12, \frac12-v<w<\frac12\right\}$. So

$$
I=\int_0^{1/2}  \frac{v}{1-v}  dv=\int_0^{1/2}  \left[\frac{1}{1-v}-1\right]  dv=\left.-\ln(1-v)-v\right|_0^{1/2}=\ln 2-1/2.
$$